# print text input in a class into another class

Tags: python, class, kivy

I need a way that, a class which has a button(go to for advanced options), at release a pop up opens(has own class) inside it there is texet inputand a button whatever user typing in it i need at clicking (write button) to send it back to the first class (that will print the texet input values)

***********python file***********

```
from kivy.app import App   
from kivy.lang import Builder   
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class btn_(BoxLayout):
    pass


class Var():
    def PP_(self):
        xx = self.textinput1.text
        print (xx)

class Editor(App):
    zozo = Var()
    def build(self):
        return btn_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Editor().run()
```

****KV file *********

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory  
<btn_>:
    Button:
        text: "Open PopUp"
        on_release: Factory.Popup().open() 
<Popup>:
    textinput1: textinput1
    BoxLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: textinput1
            hint_text: "Write something"
        Button:
            text: "Write"
            on_release: app.zozo.PP_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for passing the `TextInput.text` from class rule, `<Popup>:` in kv file to class, `Var()` in Python code is as follow:

## main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class btn_(BoxLayout):
     pass


class Var():

    def PP_(self, txt):
        print(txt)


class Editor(App):
    zozo = Var()

    def build(self):
        return btn_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Editor().run()
```

## editor.kv

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<btn_>:
    Button:
        text: "Open PopUp"
        on_release: Factory.Popup().open()

<Popup>:
    BoxLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: textinput1
            hint_text: "Write something"
        Button:
            text: "Write"
            on_release: app.zozo.PP_(textinput1.text)
```